# “The typeof operator cannot be used on a nullable reference type”

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-3.1, nullable-reference-types

I just got this error when I was trying to use `typeof(string?)` for a `SwaggerResponse` attribute parameter.

It's `The typeof operator cannot be used on a nullable reference type` in compiler

and `The typeof expression cannot be used on nullable reference types` in Rider.

**Why can't I do that? What can I do when (like in described problem) I need to emphasize in compile-time that the type is nullable?**

Comment: [#3003](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3003) C# language issue. [#1087](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1087) dotnet runtime issue